# Is it possible to use a variable in the copyTo command in Google Apps Script for Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that generates a test plan based on info from a Google Form. What I want to do is make a script that checks the B column, and if there's content in B[row number], copy cell I3 into I[row number].

Here's what I am working with:

```
var testplan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestPlan");

for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {  

var destination = testplan.getRange(3, 9);
var contentCheck = testplan.getRange("B2:B200").getValues();

if (contentCheck != '' && contentCheck != 0) {
  destination.copyTo(testplan.getRange(j, 9));
};
```

Now, if I set the copyTo from anything that's not j, like 4, it copies to I4 just fine. Otherwise, I get the error "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid."

Is there a way to use a variable here I'm not seeing? Or do I have something else gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

- You're planning to copy `I3` to `I[row]`, but you have `contentCheck` starting at `B2`, which overlaps. That overlap is what is causing the error, `"The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid."`
- You've called your source cell, `I3`, "destination", and that's confusing. Let's call it `source`. Also, you know the cell coordinates, so why not use them?
- You've declared that value inside a loop... but it never changes so instead do that before the loop, just once.
- Similarly, `contentCheck` could be loaded once, before the loop. It yields a 2-D array (an array of rows, each with a single column, in this case). You need to address it as an array, using row and column indexes, otherwise the entire array is first flattened to create a string value to compare to `''`, then parsed for an integer to compare to '0' here:

  ```
  if (contentCheck != '' && contentCheck != 0) {
  ```

  Nice thing here, once we index in to a single value, ala `contentCheck[j][0]`... that comparison can be simplified to a test for [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

  ```
  if (contentCheck[j][0]) {
  ```

  The array will be 0-based, while spreadsheet row and column indexes are 1-based. You need to adjust for that, especially since your range begins at `B2`, skipping a row. (To avoid the overlap mentioned earlier, let's say it should start at `B4` - you'll need to sort out your actual values.)

You should end up with something like this:

```
var testplan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                             .getSheetByName("TestPlan");

var source = testplan.getRange("I3");
var contentCheck = testplan.getRange("B4:B200").getValues();

for (var j = 0; j < contentCheck.length; j++) {  

  if (contentCheck[j][0])) {
    // 0-based j plus 1 to be 1-based, plus starting row
    source.copyTo(testplan.getRange(j+1+4, 9));
  };
}
```